# FIND_IN_SET or SELECT * FROM

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know the best approach for select records on basis of a bunch of codes.. Say they are codes like '4456', '4008', '2189', '6667', etc. It doesn't really matter.

I can glue those codes together in a string like '4456,4008,2189,....' and use them in the final query like WHERE FIND_IN_SET(. . . ), etc.

Or . . .

I can store them in a temporary table (some_table), prior to using them in the final query and use them like: WHERE code IN (SELECT codes FROM some_table).

What is best practice, what will on average give the best performance?

Note: I will have to go through a process up to 200 times. Every time selecting some codes one by one before doing the final query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not `WHERE col IN (4456, 4008, ..)`?

Comment: I do not write them out myself in the query, I have to select them one by one. It happens in an SP. How do I put them in such a list? I realy don't know how to do that.

Comment: "How do I put them in such a list?"  -  It depends on your application language.

Comment: SP within MySQL. Not something like PHP.

Comment: I don't see the problem? if you can put them "in a string like '4456,4008,2189,....'" - what's the difference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There is not realy a problem. I can use both methods. But would like to know what is best practice. Since I don't know how to create a list like (4456, 4008, ...) I invented the table in between so I can use WHERE code IN (SELECT codes FROM table). This is one of the solutions I presented in the question.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116434

Comment: @JGFMK. This describes that both solutions that I presented in my question, work.
Maybe there is no best practice. Thought maybe someone would mention that creating small in between tables all the time (one of the solutions), is to much overload. Or other comments like this.

Comment: I indicated the store procedure approach - by pointing to the specific @facilities answer. Specifically the prepared statement approach you build up. Gave you the way to build up the IN() ids

Comment: Thanks. Instead of the PREPARE, EXECUTE  and DEALLOCATE cycle I can just as well put @facilities (which is 'code1,code2, . .') in FIND_IN_SET isn't it? Or do I miss something.

Comment: I don't get it. If you're not going to bother with normalisation, why bother with a relational database at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try `select group_concat(codes) from table group by codes`;
it will create a list as you like (4456, 4008, ...)

Comment: Thanks for this tip. This is a third solution for what I need and I can use this instead of the table in between approach. Didn't know it could be done like this.

Answer (score 0):

Plonk this in a stored procedure

```
SET @facilities = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(facility_id) FROM facility);
@stmt = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM request WHERE facility_id IN (', @facilities, ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know the best approach for select records on basis of a bunch of codes [...] I can glue those codes together in a string and use them in the final query.

Database servers primarily deal with tables and columns. If your data is originally a list, don't concatenate the values into a string, to only ask your RDBMS to parse it : this would mean more work for your application and for the database.

Instead, you can just pass the values as parameters to an `IN` condition, like :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycode IN (?, ?, ?, ...)
```

NB : in MySQL, the maximum number of elements in an `IN` condition is controled by parameter `max_allowed_packet`, which defaults to 1000.

---

If your data is originally stored in a database table, then the `EXISTS` condition is your friend :

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM mytable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mycodes c WHERE c.code = t.code)
```